# Querying objects created within a time period

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a query, that tries to get a list of users and returns them if they were created within 30 days (1 month).

here is what I have tried,

models.py

```
class Showcase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Showcases")
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ShowcaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug')
    created_on = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Showcase
        exclude = ['id']

    def get_created_on(self, instance):
        return instance.created_on.strftime("%d %B %Y ; %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

views.py

```
class MostLikedMonthShowcasesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    Most liked showcases created within the past month
    '''
    serializer_class = ShowcaseSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self):
        last_30_days = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(30)
        return Showcase.objects.filter(created_on__lte=datetime.datetime.today(), created_on__gt=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=30)).values('created_on')
```

when I run the above code I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'created_on'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values() method returns a QuerySet containing dictionaries. So, base queryset would be

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    last_30_days = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(30)
    return Showcase.objects.filter(created_on__range=[last_30_days,datetime.datetime.today())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code that's throwing that error is not the database part, I'll bet it's this:

```
def get_created_on(self, instance):
    return instance.created_on.strftime("%d %B %Y ; %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Show how your caller for this method

Also, use the range function:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range